# I get this error in Hadoop, Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to the Hadoop system and I am running into the following error when attempting to get the file system of Hadoop (HDFS) The setup is Hadoop Running on Ubuntu Server 15.05. and a Java Program running on Windows using Java to connect and add files to the Hadoop system.

The error is:

```
    15/07/14 11:23:30 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    15/07/14 11:23:30 ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
    java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```

With the following line reference:

```
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://10.0.0.1:54310"), configuration);
```

Comment: You have to build hadoop in windows and use that package to use in windows client machine. When building hadoop in windows, it will create winutils and other native libraries in hadoop/bin

Comment: @Kumar I have downloaded the Hadoop 2.6.0 Binaries from [link](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.0/hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz ) should I move it to a specific location, however I do not see a winutils.exe inside the bin file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Answered my own question after spending 3 hours googling the problem, If anyone else experiences the problem I found the [Answer Here](http://teknosrc.com/spark-error-java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-hadoop-binaries/)

I downloaded the winutils.exe and placed it in C:/Bin/Winutils.exe

I then added the following line to my project at the start of the function

```
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutil\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you directly take the binary distribution of **Apache Hadoop 2.6.0 release** and try to run it on Microsoft Windows, then we'll encounter

```
ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
```

These are required (not optional) to run Hadoop on Windows.
For this you have to add the files separately

Just download and copy all the files of `hadoop-common-2.6.0/bin` folder and paste them to /bin folder

Refer to [this](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/39/error-util-shell-failed-locate-winutils-binary-hadoop-binary-path) and [this](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os) blog.